# how to clean variables to prevent sql injection - union select?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I've read many documents for preventing sql injection.
they said using `PDO` and `mysql_real_escape_string`.

I program BBS code(old-style...),
and people using my BBS code, 
do some simple code like :

```
select * from $g4[member_table] where mb_id='$mb_id' and mb_1='$my_option'
```

`$mb_id` do `mysql_real_escape_string`
but `$my_option` do not maybe.
so I want to clean all `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST` varibales using php function like clean_sql().

clean_sql() clear all sql statements 
when $my_option value is "1' union select * from g4_member where mb_id='admin'"

please let me knows function like clean_sql() ?

===
cleal_sql must be work with php 4.x.

Comment: If you tag `sql-injection` then the `php` tag is redundant</troll>.

Comment: @ta.speot.is// I changed. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practices when it comes to SQL injections is the same whether or not you use UNIONs or not. Same goes for `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST` or any other form of user provided data. Either use prepared statements (via PDO or MySQLi) or `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Of course, you should be taking it a step further and validating and sanitizing user provided data *before* attempting to save it into your database. Functions like [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and [`ctype_*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php) are an easy way to validate and/or sanitize data.

Comment: @John Conde// Thanks. many hostsing companies does not support PDO, so I can not change BBS code. filter_var() is a good function, but it needs php 5.2.x and over. Some use php 4.x.

Comment: 4.x has been obsolete for a very long time. You definitely shouldn't be supporting it anymore. PHP 5.2 is by far the most common version of PHP available and is pretty much the standard level of compatibility required for most PHP software available nowadays.

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj // most of hosting comany does not support prepared statement.

Comment: some hosting company provide mysql 3.x and php 4.x. OMG